# The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock on Jenkins server

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods

I'm having a problem with cocoapods.

> The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Although, I tried to remove folder **Pods**, file `Podfile.lock` and delete workspace project then opened up the terminal and typed `pod install` but still error.

Comment: I went to tab Build Phases then remove Manifest.lock and back to jenkin server touched Run button my project back to stable.

Comment: Or u can run command on terminal `bundle install`

Answer (score 11):

I used these commands to solve the problem.

```
pod deintegrate
sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
pod clean
# Open the project and delete the “Pods” folder that should be red
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: hardly related to jenkins...